# batch file to copy share drive folder to local windows D drive

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to copy folder from network drive to local window D drive using bath job but its not copying the files

```
echo off
cls

echo Would you like to do a backup?

pause

copy "S:\2017\*" "D:\TEST_BACKUP_FOLDER"

pause
```

i have mapped my network drive as S drive i am getting below message.

```
Would you like to do a backup?
Press any key to continue . . .
S:\2017\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: are you sure, there *are*  files in `S:\2017\`? Error message says: no.

Comment: yes, there is more the 1 GB data is available in that folder with many sub folders

Comment: `copy` is a "file copy" only. No subfolders. Use [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use ***xcopy*** instead, and include sub directories by adding '/s' option. You can always get help by 'copy /?' or 'xcopy /?'.

```
    echo off
    cls

    echo Would you like to do a backup?

    pause

    xcopy "S:\2017\*" "D:\TEST_BACKUP_FOLDER\" /s

    pause
```

Comment: that worked !!....i want to tweet it and add some more options like i want schedule it every alternate day at specific time and it should not over write files but it should add only new files o local drive is it possible?

Comment: how would i avoid copying same files again and again if schedule it daily. i tried /m but its asking me again and again if i want to over write...but i want its to copy only new files and omit already copied files..

Comment: Perhaps you want to copy new files and updated files. In that case, please try "xcopy /s /d"

notice the switch /d:m-d-y  Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
 If no date is given, copies only those files whose
 source time is newer than the destination time.

Comment: when i am trying below .BAT file again i am not able to copy the files to local hard disk.. i have .mdb files in DB_Backup  folder                    
   echo off
    cls
    echo Would you like to do a backup?
    pause
    xcopy "T:\DB_Backup\*" "D:\TMS_DATABASE_BACKUP\" /S /D
    pause